# NetSuite Case when statement on joined

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, case-when

I'm new to writing case statements in NetSuite and would appreciate any input with this. I'm trying to create following statement within item search, but receiving invalid expression error.

CASE WHEN {transaction.status} = "Purchase Order:Pending Receipt" THEN {transaction.expectedreceiptdate} end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN {transaction.status} = 'Pending Receipt' THEN {transaction.expectedreceiptdate} end
```

Note that you need to use single quotes in SQL statements, and you can't specify the transaction type as part of the status condition.  To work araound this, you could include the transaction type in the criteria, or add another condition within the CASE statement:

```
CASE WHEN {transaction.status} = 'Pending Receipt' AND {transaction.type} = 'Purchase Order' THEN {transaction.expectedreceiptdate} end
```

Comment: would you not also need to put the single quotes around the variable e.g. `'{transaction.status}'` also?

Comment: No, you're passing a variable to NetSuite's preprocessor, so it can insert the corresponding value for the record being searched before sending it on to the SQL engine.  If you denote it as a string using quotes, the preprocessor will ignore it and send it on as a string literal.  Bottom line: it works without quotes; it does not work with them.